# Is there something like a depth buffer in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some curves with matplotlib.
But, since these curve overlap with each other from viewport.
So only z-order can not help here.

I wonder if there is a function works like a depth buffer in matplotlib.
I'm plotting something like this.
And the red line should not always on top in 3D space.

[image]

Comment: "My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles This is probably the most commonly reported issue with mplot3d. ..." http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's difficult to do such things in matplotlib, since it's a 2D plot library with some 3D plot ability. I recommend some real 3D plot library, such as visvis, mayavi, vpython. For example, in visvis, you can create a 3D curve like:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import visvis as vv
app = vv.use()

f = vv.clf()
a = vv.cla()

angle = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 1000)
x = np.sin(angle)
y = np.cos(angle)
z = angle / 6.0
vv.plot(x, y, z, lw=10)

angle += np.pi*2/3.0
x = np.sin(angle)
y = np.cos(angle)
z = angle / 6.0 - 0.5
vv.plot(x, y, z, lc ="r", lw=10)

app.Run()
```

mayavi:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

angle = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 1000)
x = np.sin(angle)
y = np.cos(angle)
z = angle / 6.0

mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, color=(1,0,0), tube_radius=0.1)

angle += np.pi*2/3.0
x = np.sin(angle)
y = np.cos(angle)
z = angle / 6.0 - 0.5
mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, color=(0,0,1), tube_radius=0.1)

mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `fill_between` function to color the regions manually perhaps. See
the random walkers example:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/recipes.html

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/recipes-6.py

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I read the page but it doesn't seem to fit 3D plot. And it will be almost impossible to figure out how to fill the right region.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a pain for sure. I think it could work if you really  really wanted it to. . .

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think I will find a workaround. Using python here is just for simple test.