# Gnuplot: Drawing 3d blocks with correct depth order using splot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm extending [Hagen Wierstorf's scripts for drawing cubes](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-cubes/) to plot blocks of arbitrary sizes.

Here's my code:

```
reset

set terminal qt size 700,524 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'

# color definitions
set cbrange [1:10]
set style fill transparent solid 1.0
set palette defined (\
1 '#ff4c4d',\
2 '#ce4c7d',\
3 '#ae559e',\
4 '#df866d',\
5 '#ffb66d',\
6 '#ffe7cf',\
7 '#cecece',\
8 '#6d6d6d',\
9 '#4c4c8e',\
10 '#4c4cef')
set style line  1 lc rgb '#ff2727' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line  2 lc rgb '#b90046' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line  3 lc rgb '#8b0b74' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line  4 lc rgb '#d1512e' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line  5 lc rgb '#ff972f' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line  6 lc rgb '#ffddba' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line  7 lc rgb '#b9b9b9' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line  8 lc rgb '#2e2e2e' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line  9 lc rgb '#00005d' lt 1 lw 0.5
set style line 10 lc rgb '#0000e8' lt 1 lw 0.5

unset key
unset border
unset tics
unset colorbox
set view equal xyz

# load block function
load 'block.fct'

set pm3d hidden3d
set pm3d implicit
unset hidden3d

set lmargin 2
set rmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set tmargin 0
# get block positions from file
add_block(x,y,z,h,l,w,c) = sprintf('block(%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%i) w l ls %i,',x,y,z,h,l,w,c,c)
CMD = ''
stats 'proofblocks3.txt' u 1:(CMD = CMD.add_block($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)) nooutput
set xrange [0:4]
set yrange [0:4]
set zrange [0:3]
CMD = 'splot '.CMD.'1/0 w l ls 2'
# plot block
eval(CMD)
```

Content of block.fct:

```
# gnuplot function to create a cube
#
# Usage: block(x, y, z, w, l, h, c)
block(x,y,z,w,l,h,c) = sprintf('<echo "\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\
%f %f %f %i\n\n"',\
0.1+x,0.1+y,0.1+z,c,\
0.1+x,0.1+y,(h-0.1)+z,c,\
0.1+x,(l-0.1)+y,(h-0.1)+z,c,\
0.1+x,(l-0.1)+y,0.1+z,c,\
0.1+x,0.1+y,0.1+z,c,\
(w-0.1)+x,0.1+y,0.1+z,c,\
(w-0.1)+x,0.1+y,h-0.1+z,c,\
(w-0.1)+x,(l-0.1)+y,h-0.1+z,c,\
(w-0.1)+x,(l-0.1)+y,0.1+z,c,\
(w-0.1)+x,0.1+y,0.1+z,c,\
0.1+x,0.1+y,0.1+z,c,\
(w-0.1+x),0.1+y,0.1+z,c,\
(w-0.1+x),(l-0.1)+y,0.1+z,c,\
0.1+x,(l-0.1+y),0.1+z,c,\
0.1+x,0.1+y,0.1+z,c,\
0.1+x,0.1+y,(h-0.1+z),c,\
(w-0.1)+x,0.1+y,(h-0.1+z),c,\
(w-0.1)+x,(l-0.1)+y,(h-0.1+z),c,\
0.1+x,(l-0.1)+y,(h-0.1+z),c,\
0.1+x,0.1+y,(h-0.1)+z,c\
)
```

The problem is that, when a plane (a side of a block) is longer than another in front of it, I suppose because gnuplot doesn't work like a ray tracer, it plots that larger plane in front of plane closer to the viewers because it has a point that's closer to the viewer:

[image: Long block in the middle covers two blocks in front]

Coordinates used for the above image - proofblocks3.txt content:

```
# x y z w l h color
0   0   0   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   3   1   2
2   0   0   1   1   1   3
0   1   0   1   1   1   4
2   1   0   1   1   1   5
0   2   0   1   1   1   6
2   2   0   1   1   1   7
```

Is there a way to get around this problem - as in have the surfaces plotted in the correct depth order?

Comment: Could you also give the content of `proofblocks3.txt` for testing? In the meanwhile try `set pm3d depthorder`, see second example at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/hidden2.html

Comment: Hi @Christoph, I've posted the content of 'proofblocks3.txt'. Unfortunately 'depthorder' did not change anything in the plot. Please be advised that I corrected the main script to correct "set unhidden3d" to "unset hidden3d". Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I have no idea how you could get it working with gnuplot. With only `set hidden3d` and no `pm3d` settings it works, but you don't get colors ;) I've read, that `set pm3d hidden3d` works only in very special cases. That's where gnuplot hits its limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Gnuplot is a 2D plot program with some mock 3D capabilities.

In fact, the same issue exists for other 2D plot programs like matplotlib for python.

To create true 3D plot, one should consider MATLAB (crude) or Mayavi for Python (See: [Is there something like a depth buffer in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193709/is-there-something-like-a-depth-buffer-in-matplotlib)).