# python - 3D visualisation of surfaces and shapes in vector graphics

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, vector-graphics

In view of a comment to the original question, I want to stress the following two points that should apply to an answer to this question:

1) The final plot should be a true vector graphic, similar to what the pgfplots/tikz package in latex produce.

2) The final plot should be a correct 3D plot containing several elements, so the plotting package will probably need to use z-buffering to project and render correctly.

I would like to visualise/plot 3D surfaces and geometric shapes in a single image using python. I am interested in 3D visualisation in general, but for now I am trying to do the following: I would like to plot a saddle shape in 3D (as a surface plot of an appropriate function, for example) and in addition display a 3D sphere that is tangent at a certain point of the saddle. Can this be done using matplotlib alone or do I need to use more sophisticated 3D packages like VTK? Even if it can be done in matplotlib, would you recommend matplotlib for such an application or should I use a program specifically built for this purpose?

To give you an idea of what I want to achieve using only python, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426969/tikz-pgfplots-plotting-3d-surface-with-sphere). This was done using pgfplots in latex, but as I mention in that question, there are limitations for that package. It's not python, either.

I am not interested in a photorealistic appearance or fancy rendering. This is for a physics/maths application and I would like the image to have the "look" of plots you get with mplot3D or pgfplots in latex (so that surfaces are rendered like [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_radial_demo.html) in appearance). I have had a look at 3D rendering packages for python and though I cannot really quantify the reason for this (I think it might be the lighting and raster graphics), the output of many of them looks more like something out of a video game than a scientific publication (though this is probably intended for those renderers).

I am aware that this is a rather broad question and if there are objections to this I am happy to rephrase the question or make it more specific. However, I believe that it is interesting to have an answer to the question of whether general 3D visualisation of shapes can and should be done using matplotlib.

Comment: Try [MayaVI](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html), it has served me well in the past.

Comment: Is it possible to produce plots that look like the one that I linked to with mayavi or vtk? As I mentioned in my question, I want a clean, publication-quality image like the ones produced using mplot3D.

Comment: I guess the reason I find the mplot3D plots appealing is that they produce vector graphics, while I think many renderers produce raster graphics. So ideally I would want to visualise shapes and surfaces and export them as vector graphics images.

Comment: I would also suggest MayaVI or Matplotlib. In my opinion, VTK is not as straight forward to use as the other two.

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib and mplot3d may not fit your needs as matplotlib does not perform 3d rendering (see [Is there something like a depth buffer in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193709/is-there-something-like-a-depth-buffer-in-matplotlib)). However, VTK may be too heavy for what you want to do.

Here is an example that what you can do with the visvis package: (https://github.com/almarklein/visvis)

```
import visvis as vv
import numpy as np

# Saddle surface.
x_saddle = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
y_saddle = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
x_saddle, y_saddle = np.meshgrid(x_saddle, y_saddle)
z_saddle = x_saddle**2/10. - y_saddle**2/10.

# Sphere
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

radius = 2.0
x_sphere = radius * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y_sphere = radius * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z_sphere = 2.0 + radius * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

vv.figure()

# Plot the surfaces
vv.surf(X, Y, Z)
vv.surf(x, y, z)

app = vv.use()
app.Run()
```

[image: Saddle shape and sphere rendered with visvis]

Note that you can do something very similar with Mayavi, yet the axis look to me better with visvis:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

# Saddle surface.
x_saddle = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
y_saddle = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
x_saddle, y_saddle = np.meshgrid(x_saddle, y_saddle)
z_saddle = x_saddle**2/10. - y_saddle**2/10.

# Sphere
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

radius = 2
x_sphere = radius * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y_sphere = radius * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z_sphere = 2.0 + radius * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))


# Plot the surface.
mlab.mesh(x_saddle, y_saddle, z_saddle)
mlab.mesh(x_radius, y_radius, z_radius)

mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

[image: Saddle shape and sphere rendered with Mayavi]

Comment: This looks promising. However, can these be exported as vector graphics or are they bitmaps? Also, they do not quite have the same look as something plotted with mplot3D. Can this in general be made similar in appearance by playing around with the plot settings of these applications?
I think what I am after is an image like those that you would get using Asymptote or the pgf/TikZ package of latex, but using python.

Comment: You cannot obtain vector graphics from visvis (https://github.com/almarklein/visvis/wiki/Publishing), yet it seems possible from Mayavi (http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_figure.html)
I doubt that it can be possible to have exactly the same apparence of mplot3d, but I may be wrong. Yet it should be doable to play with the plot settings to get something that can be published.

Comment: There is also Vispy (http://vispy.org/plot.html#module-vispy.plot) but it seems to lack (for now) of a high-level API such as mplot3d.

Comment: I have come across VisPy when researching for this question. However, apart from not having a high-level API yet, they are also not currently working on exporting to vector graphics. I am surprised that there is no package like TikZ for python. A flexible, comprehensive 3D plotting package to produce publication-quality (vector-graphics) 3D plots, more than what mplot3D offers, would be highly useful. TikZ is powerful, but limited.

Comment: So basically you have two constraints: 1- ability to export vector graphics and 2- z-buffering to compose several shapes. If I'm right, it would be interesting to put that constraints clearly at the top of your question. Also, it would be nice if you add an example of what you expect to get in Python, but with TikZ. It would set a target. I'll complete my answer to be as exhaustive as possible. However, if we are sticking with Python, it seems to me that either we stick to mplot3d (but no z-buffering), or we have to switch on a real 3d rendered, but with raster exports.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect your suggestions. I have also added a link to a question I posted on tex.stackexchange, which gives an idea of what I would like to achieve using python alone